# Street fights that ends on ground is BJJ is the ultimate solution?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, self-defense

Is BJJ is the ultimate fight method/ technique on the ground for street fight or is it most a sport technique? 
Is there any evidence for the benefits of BJJ on ground in street fights? Are there any other better methods/ techniques in ground street fight?

Comment: Dear @mitro, as an expert in Krav Maga this question stems from a need to add some techniques of BJJ to Krav Maga. So it might sound a way but it is very practical. Concerning my previous question - as can be seen from the popularity I think many people are interested in. I'll be glad if you can answer my question and give specific examples for the technique.

Comment: You should be more specific with your questions, that's all I would like to see as I really cant answer something that is really depending on the situation. - better methods/techniques for ground street fight?? BJJ is a martial art with a lot of techniques focusing on ground techniques ... which one you mean? In Krav-Maga it is priority to avoid the ground but being able to get out of different holds etc. to get up again. ... thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I'll try to add an example that might add some insight to the question/ answer. Suppose a heavy person sits on your bally. The BJJ there is a way to bridge your back and trow him away is it practical in street fight?

Comment: @Avi You should rewrite your question to ask specifically about your more specific question. (The answer is that, yes, BJJ players have a little bit of experience in that situation.)

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here.  You'd be better off splitting them up.  "Is BJJ useful in a street fight and what evidence is there?" "Is this specific technique practical in a fight?" etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "ultimate method" in a street fight.

Ground grappling is really good if you end up in a one on one fight, on the ground, with no weapons involved.  Fights tend to go to the ground because people have bad balance, it's relatively easy to trip or get knocked over something, and the tackle/bum rush doesn't require a lot of skill to use.

Untrained combatants usually go for a mount and pound, which mostly limits the target to the head.  Meanwhile on the ground everything is a target for potential grapple and lock - ankles, wrists, arms, etc. and that's where ground grapplers do great - they have more options, they have more targets, and while the untrained person has only one place where they feel comfortable attacking from, the grappler can attack from many positions.

However, if you are restraining or looking to get a grapple on with someone and they have a friend or several friends running up to attack you - you've lost your mobility and probably a lot of situational awareness.  You can find numerous street fight videos where someone gets kicked in the head while they're trying to ground fight, or, worse, attacked with a weapon.

The second situation that is bad is when a weapon comes out and you don't realize it.  This is true in all situations, however with a ground grapple you are in full contact and have no "give" to escape like you might when you are standing.  Just as much as any body part is a target for a grappler, any body part is also a target for a knife, or worse, a gun.

Grappling is a great set of tools to have in any self defense plan.  BJJ is one of the most popular types of ground grappling, but you can find grappling styles all around the world, because, well, wrestling is as old as humanity.  Pretty much every combative art in history has SOME grappling in it, even if it's not as popular or taught as commonly in the current day.  However, against multiple opponents or against weapons, it's not sufficient by itself.